# "default_secret_name" is no longer applicable for Kubernetes v1.24.0 and above

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform, workload-identity

I'm using Terraform workload-identity module , to create Kubernetes service account in Google Cloud. When i apply the changes, I'm getting below warning.

> "default_secret_name" is no longer applicable for Kubernetes v1.24.0
> and above │ │   with
> module.app-workload-identity.kubernetes_service_account_v1.main, │
> on ../../modules/workload-identity/main.tf line 57, in resource
> "kubernetes_service_account_v1" "main": │   57: resource
> "kubernetes_service_account_v1" "main" { │ │ Starting from version
> 1.24.0 Kubernetes does not automatically generate a token for service accounts, in this case, "default_secret_name" will be  │ empty

**Workload-Identity main.tf**

```
locals {
  service_account_tmp = var.google_service_account_email== "" ? "projects/${var.project_id}/serviceAccounts/cloudsql-sa@${var.project_id}.iam.gserviceaccount.com" : var.google_service_account_email
  service_id = "projects/${var.project_id}/serviceAccounts/cloudsql-sa@${var.project_id}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  k8s_sa_gcp_derived_name = "serviceAccount:${var.project_id}.svc.id.goog[${var.namespace}/${local.output_k8s_name}]"
  gcp_sa_email            = var.google_service_account_email

  # This will cause terraform to block returning outputs until the service account is created
  k8s_given_name       = var.k8s_sa_name != null ? var.k8s_sa_name : var.name
  output_k8s_name      = var.use_existing_k8s_sa ? local.k8s_given_name : kubernetes_service_account.main[0].metadata[0].name
  output_k8s_namespace = var.use_existing_k8s_sa ? var.namespace : kubernetes_service_account.main[0].metadata[0].namespace
}

# resource "google_service_account" "cluster_service_account" {
  # GCP service account ids must be < 30 chars matching regex ^[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{4,28}[a-z0-9])$
  # KSA do not have this naming restriction.
  # account_id   = substr(var.name, 0, 30)
  # display_name = substr("GCP SA bound to K8S SA ${local.k8s_given_name}", 0, 100)
  # project      = var.project_id
# }
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "k8s_namespace" {
  metadata {
    name = var.namespace
  }
}

# resource "kubernetes_secret_v1" "main" {
#  metadata {
#    name      = var.name
#    namespace = var.namespace
#    annotations = {
#      "kubernetes.io/service-account.name"      = kubernetes_service_account_v1.main.metadata.0.name
#      "kubernetes.io/service-account.namespace" = kubernetes_service_account_v1.main.metadata.0.namespace
#    }
#    generate_name = "${kubernetes_service_account_v1.main.metadata.0.name}-token-"
#  }
#  type = "kubernetes.io/service-account-token"
#  wait_for_service_account_token = true
#}

resource "kubernetes_service_account" "main" {
  count = var.use_existing_k8s_sa ? 0 : 1
  metadata {
    name      = var.name
    namespace = var.namespace
    annotations = {
      "iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account" = var.google_service_account_email
    }
  }
}


module "annotate-sa" {
  source  = "terraform-google-modules/gcloud/google//modules/kubectl-wrapper"
  version = "~> 2.0.2"

  enabled          = var.use_existing_k8s_sa && var.annotate_k8s_sa
  skip_download    = true
  cluster_name     = var.cluster_name
  cluster_location = var.location
  project_id       = var.project_id

  kubectl_create_command  = "kubectl annotate --overwrite sa -n ${local.output_k8s_namespace} ${local.k8s_given_name} iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account=${local.gcp_sa_email}"
  kubectl_destroy_command = "kubectl annotate sa -n ${local.output_k8s_namespace} ${local.k8s_given_name} iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account-"
}

resource "google_service_account_iam_member" "main" {
  service_account_id = local.service_id
  role               = "roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser"
  member             = local.k8s_sa_gcp_derived_name
}
```

As per the [this](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/service_account) documentation , I have tried to add the resource "kubernetes_secret_v1" to create a service account token. But still getting the same warning message.

Comment: Please let me know whether the shared info was helpful and the issue resolved?. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries.

Comment: @SaiChandraGadde, from your answer, I need to use the alternative solution or Gitlab issue fixed using manifest? With the manifest, I stuck how to update the terraform resource. So I'm trying the alternative solution

Comment: You can use both, better try alternative solution and let me know if this works.

Comment: Alternate solution works fine... How to update the terraform resource with the manifest (https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-kubernetes/pull/1792/files/04140ea649a2dcdaffb2da3f85dde35320fd97c8#diff-c743e045ffac6c322ed857bb5f5b6efa1b2d854c02de71996f9d937e0242dd03)

Comment: will look into it and let you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [git issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-kubernetes/pull/1792) kubernetes_service_account issue has been successfully fixed using this [manifest](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-kubernetes/pull/1792/files/04140ea649a2dcdaffb2da3f85dde35320fd97c8#diff-c743e045ffac6c322ed857bb5f5b6efa1b2d854c02de71996f9d937e0242dd03).

I found this [alternative solution](https://github.com/yasserisa/terraform-google-kubernetes-engine/commit/a1972155e856c702c13f1196a202f65b71378bde) where changes are made using the terraform resource kubernetes_manifest to manually generate the service accounts along with their secret.

Can you try the main.tf file and let me know if this works.

For more information follow this [Issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-kubernetes/issues/1724).

Answer (score 1):

We faced a similar issue very recently. What worked for us was defining the `secret` in the `kubernetes_service_account_v1` terraform resource.

Here's an example:

```
resource "kubernetes_service_account_v1" "svc_test" {
   metadata {
      name = "svc-test"
      namespace = "test"
   }
   secret {
    name = "svc-test-token"
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_secret_v1" "svc_test_token" {
  metadata {
    name = "${kubernetes_service_account_v1.svc_test.metadata[0].name}-token"
    annotations = {
      "kubernetes.io/service-account.name" = kubernetes_service_account_v1.svc_test.metadata[0].name
    }
    namespace = "test"
    generate_name = "${kubernetes_service_account_v1.svc_test.metadata[0].name}-token"

  }
  type = "kubernetes.io/service-account-token"
  
  wait_for_service_account_token = true
}
```

We found that without this, the `secret` gets created with the `serviceaccount` reference but there is no reference of the `secret` in the `serviceaccount`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Terraform AWS provider documentation [warning about the deprecation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/service_account_v1#default_secret_name) of `default_secret_name` in `service_account_v1` resource, the `kubernetes_secret_v1` resource [should be used to created](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/secret_v1#example-usage-service-account-token) the secret to hold the Service Account token, since Service Account tokens are no longer created automatically in K8s versions starting 1.24 and beyond. These explicitly created tokens are only needed by legacy software, which are unable to use the new [TokenRequest API](https://v1-24.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#service-account-token-secrets) (see [K8s docs](https://v1-24.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/authentication-resources/token-request-v1/)).

When you do need to explicitly create a Secret with the Service Account token, to support legacy behavior, the following works very well:

```golang
resource "kubernetes_service_account_v1" "this" {
  provider = kubernetes.minikube
  metadata {
    name      = local.service_account_name
    namespace = local.namespace
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_secret_v1" "this" {
  provider = kubernetes.minikube
  metadata {
    name      = "${kubernetes_service_account_v1.this.metadata[0].name}-token"
    namespace = local.namespace
    annotations = {
      "kubernetes.io/service-account.name" = kubernetes_service_account_v1.this.metadata[0].name
    }
  }
  type = "kubernetes.io/service-account-token"
}
```

[image: default secret attribute deprecation notice]

Comment: Please do not use images to paste logs, nor errors, nor source code nor documentation https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: I see your point @N1ngu. Though I did included a link to the documented warning "about the deprecation" in `kubernetes_service_account_v1` resource in my answer. Screenshot is for historical reference, in case the warning is removed from the docs.

Comment: Nobody proposed to replace the screenshot with a link. For historical reference, you can copypaste the doc fragment instead of a screenshot! And for historical reference, you can link to a specific version of most documentation systems.

Comment: @N1ngu, feel free yo use the "edit" button to format in a best way possible